# This site can’t provide a secure connection Google App Engine

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, web

So I deployed my web app using python on google app engine. When i visit the link for example https://example.ew.r.appspot.com/ I get no response, it just displays can't provide secure connection. 
But when i remove the region id the site loads normally. ex https://example.appspot.com/

Does Anyone know why?

Comment: Glad to see this. I am facing this issue for the last three days. Mine is a basic node app. Being a newbie to GCP I thought my configuration was the issue. Thanks for raising.

Comment: It seems you having a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error. Could you try to fix it following [these steps](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/)?

Comment: no this really didn't do anything, as soon I remove the region id ew.r the site loads fine

Comment: Could you open this issue under [this Public Issue tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299) specifying your project ID so we can investigate from our side?

Comment: @mrJoker , I have created an issue in the issue tracker mentioned above. I will update this thread once I get a response.